# How to print the path of the html file in response in Django test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I want to know which template file django is reading when I'm testing.

I use MEZZANINE for my website. I tried to change the home page. But I'm not sure which file to change.

```py
from django.test import TestCase
import os
# Create your tests here.

class ProjectTests(TestCase):

    def test_homepage(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        #print dir(response)
        print response.template_name
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I expect to print the absolute path of `response.template_name`. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure is it what you want, but Django's test suite implements assertTemplateUsed method, use it like: `self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'index.html')`, I believe it looks in setting's template dirs for filename.